There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier
.net SDK 8 Android project build log shows below error and creates all ABI combined build.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(154,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm'.
    /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/8.0.303/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(154,5): message NETSDK1084: There is no application host available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'android-arm64'.

my .csproj configuration
<TargetFramework>net8.0-android</TargetFramework>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>29</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<Nullable>disable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
<BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>false</BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>
<RuntimeIdentifiers>android-arm;android-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
<AndroidApplication>true</AndroidApplication>

I want to build only for arm64-v8a and armabi-v7a which is 'android-arm64' and 'android-arm' in .net as 'RuntimeIdentifier'.

Why the following lines?
<BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>false</BuildWithMSBuildOnMono>
<AndroidApplication>true</AndroidApplication>.

I've never seen them in a net8-android project.
<RuntimeIdentifiers>android-arm;android-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> is correct for what you want.

that both lines were already there since i've created project. I know android-arm;android-arm64 is correct as i've seen it on official doc too but when i'm building the project then it generates all 4 abis apk files.

BuildWithMSBuildOnMono - a Google search reveals it has something to do with Xamarin.Essentials which I've never used, AndroidApplication is documented, but there is also a warning about it. Why not comment them both out and see if it builds? It seems odd that they have been there since you created the project. If you make a HelloAndroid project via the standard VS2022 Android template, you don't get either. If you can't sort it out, raise an issue https://github.com/dotnet/android/issues

I've tried by removing that lines but there is no effect.

Can you build and deploy a new project created by the standard AndroidApplication template to an Android device? If you want to test a sample net8-android project you could download NavigationGraph8Net8 from my Github which was built with the original Net8 RC release. Its csproj is using the same RuntimeIdentifiers you want to use. https://github.com/gmck/NavigationGraph8Net8. You can see in the repo that it is a conversion of the Xamarin Android NavigationGraph8 project.
